# testing for 'Dangling Cursor'

Tags: tools, penetration-test, databases, automated-testing

While reading the updated Top 25 exploits in the Common Weakness Enumeration I came across an exploit that I was not familiar with. It is numbered [CWE-619: Dangling Database Cursor](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/619.html).

I was wondering if there are any tools, similar to a Sql Injection fuzzer, that I could use to test my server for possible exploits. I am running Windows Server 08 with Oracle 10g on IIS 7. FOSS would be great, but I would pay some for a solid testing suite that can check for this exploit.

Comment: why the down votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any publicly available toolsets for this at the moment, but there's been a couple of interesting white-papers and postings recently on the general security dangers of cursors

Two from David Litchfield [here](http://www.v3rity.com/global_cursors.pdf) and [here](http://www.v3rity.com/sys_refcursors.pdf)

and an interesting blog posting from Pete Finnigan [here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001349.htm)